# Neither an FOEventHandler, nor a Renderer could be found for this output format

Tags: java, apache-fop, docx4j

I am doing a conversion from docx to pdf format. I successfully did the variable replacement and have a WordprocessingMLPackage template.

I have tried both approches. The old deprcated version of converting to pdf and the newer method. Both fails giving this exception error

> Don't know how to handle "application/pdf" as an output format.
>   Neither an FOEventHandler, nor a Renderer could be found for this
>   output format. Error: UnsupportedOpertaionException

I have tried everything I can. This thing works on my local machine but now at my workplace. I think I have all the necessary jars. Can u please instruct what course of action should I take.

Code : 
Method 1:

```
Docx4J.toPDF(template, new FileOutputStream("newPdf.pdf"));
```

Method 2:

```
public static void createPDF(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String outputPath) {
        try {

            // 2) Prepare Pdf settings
            PdfSettings pdfSettings = new PdfSettings();

            // 3) Convert WordprocessingMLPackage to Pdf
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    outputPath));
            PdfConversion converter = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion(
                    template);
            converter.output(out, pdfSettings);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Both are giving the same error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This might be useful...I am missing the Meta-INF folder. Actually for some reasons I had no access to importing the 3rd party docx4j into my project so the hacky way was to put the class files in the same hierarchical structure in build->private->classes->library. Could that be an issue? If yes please tell where to put this META-INF

Comment: What FOP jar do you have on your classpath?

Comment: I have fop-1.1.jar

Comment: Since I am copying the .class files into the build->private->classes->library directory it might be possible that Meta-Inf is missing or not being able to be detected. Can I manually set the renderer and Handler?

Comment: Additionally I am using docx4j-3.2.1.jar Do i need to use 3.3?

Comment: You can use either.  Just use the correct dependencies for the version of docx4j you choose.  What environment are you trying to make this work in?

Comment: Ok. Well I have a project in which I am using it. The company uses a different build system and docx4j is not there in it yet. The process of importing it into that is quite long given my project deadline. So this is the hacky way I use by copying the "org" folder containing ".class" files into the build->private->classes->library. IDE is eclipse

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved. The problem was that the required fop-1.1.jar was there on my eclipse classpath but it was not there on the local server classpath. I added them there and it worked like a charm.